# How to make R take values from another column?

Tags: r

I have two tables with data in R. What I want is to inherit values from the v2 column of Table 1 to the v2 column of Table 2 with the same ID (v1 column in both tables) and if the value in the v2 column of table2 is 0.

The columns in the tables look like this:

**Table 1**

| v1 | v2 |
| --- | --- |
| 11 | 1 |
| 22 | 1 |
| 33 | 0 |
| 44 | 1 |
| 55 | 1 |

**Table 2**

| v1 | v2 |
| --- | --- |
| 11 | 2 |
| 22 | 3 |
| 33 | 7 |
| 44 | 7 |
| 55 | 0 |
| 66 | 0 |

**What I am expecting for results**

| v1 | v2 |
| --- | --- |
| 11 | 2 |
| 22 | 3 |
| 33 | 7 |
| 44 | 7 |
| 55 | 1 |
| 66 | 0 |

Does anyone know how I could manage this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have now corrected the table to the right format. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df2)[df1, v2 := fifelse(v2 == 0, i.v2, v2), on = .(v1)]
```

-output

```
> df2
      v1    v2
   <int> <int>
1:    11     2
2:    22     3
3:    33     5
4:    44     7
5:    55     1
6:    66     0
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do `left_join`:

```r
library(dplyr)

table2 %>% 
  left_join(table1, by = "v1") %>% 
  mutate(v2 = ifelse(v2.x == 0, v2.y, v2.x),
         .keep = "unused")
```

This returns

```r
# A tibble: 6 x 2
     v1    v2
  <dbl> <dbl>
1    11     2
2    22     3
3    33     5
4    44     7
5    55     1
6    66    NA
```

Note: There is no value for 66 in `table1`.

Depending on the *real*  structure of your tables, a `full_join` might be an option.